# accessing index of one array for another array

Tags: angularjs, arrays

I want to access the index of dashboardCtrl.labels in dashboardCtrl.labelColors which is another array.I have tried the following but no success. If I print just {{$index}} it is getting printed successfully}}

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="i in dashboardCtrl.labels">
                              <div id="circle" style="background:green"></div>{{i}}
                              <label>{{dashboardCtrl.labelColors[{{$index}}]}}</label>
                          </div>
```

Comment: try just index not {{index}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the following. Just `$index` in `{{dashboardCtrl.labelColors[$index]}}` instead of `{{dashboardCtrl.labelColors[{{$index}}]}}`

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="i in dashboardCtrl.labels">
    <div id="circle" style="background:green"></div>{{i}}
    <label>{{dashboardCtrl.labelColors[$index]}}</label>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

Apply CSS style attribute dynamically in Angular JS

```
ng-style="{'background-color': dashboardCtrl.labelColors[$index]}"
```

Comment: Yes that solved my problem is this the same way to assign style dynamically <div id="circle" style="background:{{dashboardCtrl.labelColors[$index]}}"></div>{{i}}

Comment: we use `ng-style` for that. I am adding a small demo in the answer's edit part.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need nested brackets {{ }}. Try this

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="i in dashboardCtrl.labels">
    <div id="circle" style="background:green"></div>{{i}}                              
    <label>{{dashboardCtrl.labelColors[$index]}}</label>
</div>
```